# Using DAX to create a summary table of COUNTS allowing GLOBAL FILTERS to take place

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Hello lovely people of SO,

I have the following table:

| PRODUCT | REGION | REP | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REG-YH-67 | NORTH | JANE | JUNE |
| REG-YH-67 | NORTH | JANE | MARCH |
| REG-YH-67 | NORTH | JANE | DECEMBER |
| REG-YH-89 | NORTH | JANE | SEPTEMBER |
| REG-YH-67 | OUT-OF-REG | JANE | JUNE |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE | MARCH |
| REG-YH-9 | WEST | ALEX | DECEMBER |
| REG-YH-9 | WEST | ALEX | SEPTEMBER |
| REG-YH-30 | WEST | WILL | JUNE |
| REG-YH-33 | WEST | WILL | MARCH |
| REG-YH-33 | OUT-OF-REG | WILL | DECEMBER |
| REG-YH-33 | WEST | WILL | SEPTEMBER |
| REG-YH-33 | WEST | MARTHA | JUNE |
| REG-YH-33 | WEST | MARTHA | MARCH |
| REG-YH-67 | OUT-OF-REG | JANE | DECEMBER |
| REG-YH-67 | OUT-OF-REG | JANE | SEPTEMBER |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE | JUNE |
| REG-YH-89 | NORTH | JANE | MARCH |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE | DECEMBER |
| REG-YH-9 | WEST | JANE | SEPTEMBER |
| REG-YH-9 | OUT-OF-REG | JANE | JUNE |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE | MARCH |
| REG-YH-67 | OUT-OF-REG | JANE | DECEMBER |
| REG-YH-9 | NORTH | JANE | SEPTEMBER |
| REG-YH-67 | OUT-OF-REG | JANE | JUNE |
| REG-YH-9 | OUT-OF-REG | JANE | MARCH |

This is the source file that I use in a power bi doc that I want to create, I have 2 global filters in my main page which are `REP` and `MONTH`, and I want to learn how to use DAX to create a summary table that will plot the top 3 best selling `PRODUCTs` for each `REGION`

if we do not use the filters then the desired table would look like this:

| REGION | BEST SELLING | 2ND BEST SELLING | 3RD BEST SELLING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NORTH | REG-YH-9 | REG-YH-67 | REG-YH-89 |
| OUT-OF-REG | REG-YH-67 | REG-YH-9 | REG-YH-33 |
| WEST | REG-YH-33 | REG-YH-9 | REG-YH-30 |

but I want to be able to use my global filters in the PBI dashboard and perhaps filter by `REP`= MARTHA & JANE so that my summary table would recalculate/turn to be:

| REGION | BEST SELLING | 2ND BEST SELLING | 3RD BEST SELLING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NORTH | REG-YH-9 | REG-YH-67 | REG-YH-89 |
| OUT-OF-REG | REG-YH-67 | REG-YH-9 | null |
| WEST | REG-YH-33 | REG-YH-9 | null |

I dont know if there is a way to do this on Power BI but if you guys can help me out I will be so thankful I will be very attentive and diligent to read all of your comments THANKS A MILLION!

Comment: What should be returned if more than one product is equally best-selling?

Comment: @JosWoolley, It's not the first issue with this data set. It should be one product in cell. So if it's a pair then rank by name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 3 measures changing the rank to 1,2 or 3

[image]
[image]

```
Measure = 
    
VAR tbl =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            'table'
            ,"@rank",RANKX(VALUES('table'[PRODUCT]),CALCULATE( COUNT('table'[PRODUCT]), ALLEXCEPT('table','table'[PRODUCT],'table'[REGION])), , ,Dense)
        )
VAR temp =  SELECTCOLUMNS( FILTER(tbl, [@rank] = 1),"a", 'table'[PRODUCT])
VAR result =    CALCULATE(MAX('table'[PRODUCT]),'table'[PRODUCT] IN temp)
RETURN result
```

Below solution accounts for row totals if this is important.

```
Measure1 = 
    
VAR tbl1 =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            'table'
            ,"@rank",RANKX(VALUES('table'[PRODUCT]),CALCULATE( COUNT('table'[PRODUCT]), ALLEXCEPT('table','table'[PRODUCT],'table'[REGION])), , ,Dense)
        )
VAR temp1 =  SELECTCOLUMNS( FILTER(tbl1, [@rank] = 1),"a", 'table'[PRODUCT])
VAR result1 =    CALCULATE(MAX('table'[PRODUCT]),'table'[PRODUCT] IN temp1)

VAR tbl2 =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            'table'
            ,"@rank",RANKX(VALUES('table'[PRODUCT]),CALCULATE( COUNT('table'[PRODUCT]), ALLEXCEPT('table','table'[PRODUCT])), , ,Dense)
        )
VAR temp2 =  SELECTCOLUMNS( FILTER(tbl2, [@rank] = 1),"a", 'table'[PRODUCT])
VAR result2 =    CALCULATE(MAX('table'[PRODUCT]),'table'[PRODUCT] IN temp2)




RETURN  IF(ISFILTERED('table'[REGION]), result1, result2)
```

[image]

Comment: A good solution. Upvote!)

Comment: Perhaps the OP will clarify re the row totals, though again, for the example given I would not have expected to see REG-YH-9 as being simultaneously the Best Selling and 2nd Best Selling for all Regions.

Comment: Good spot. Does this need more logic to handle row totals? I thought it would already be covered but clearly not.

Comment: @JosWoolley, how to follow you/posts? )

Comment: @David. Facing a similar issue with my own attempt at a solution.

Comment: @Mik 'Follow' me?! There's not much worth following!

Comment: I'll update my solution to account for totals

Comment: @David Hello, Can you achieve the same  using only one measure? To get the rank numbers (1st, 2nd, 3rd) from creating a simple table(using Enter data) then put it in the column. What I need to know is that is it possible to bind them to a single measure ? If so, how ? Thanks.

Comment: Probably. You could use your table containing 1,2,3 as the column headers and get the context for the TopN from there. If you have a similar problem, might be best to ask a new question.

Comment: DAVID thank you so much for this answer and for your thought process behind it, mora than helping me out you are teaching someone and that is worth applauding! I will be selecting your code as my answer .... to answer some of your question, YES there will be times where there is a TIE between best selling products but for the practicality of this task it will not matter which one is which, but in the future I will be interested in creating a column that will show the TOTAL next to each row... THANK YOU GUYS AGAIN FOR YOUR HELP

Answer (score 2):

How about this, Ron Rosenfeld? )

It's a stepwise measure. So, it's easy to get and idea how it's works. You need 3 equal measures, but don't forget to chage names and TopPos Values for TOP2 and TOP3.

```
TOP1 = 
VAR TopPos = 1
VAR currentRegion = SELECTEDVALUE('table'[REGION]) 
-- VAR currentRegion = VALUES('table'[REGION]) -- if you want to have a value in total
VAR tblCount =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE('table','table'[PRODUCT],'table'[REGION])
        ,"Count",CALCULATE(CountRows('table'))*1000000
    )
VAR tblCountIndex =
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            tblCount
            ,"NameIndex",RANKX(VALUES('table'[PRODUCT]),[PRODUCT])
        )

VAR filteredByRegion = 
        FILTER(
            tblCountIndex
            ,[REGION]=currentRegion 
          --, [REGION] IN currentRegion --for value in total
        )

VAR tblRanked=
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            filteredByRegion
            ,"Rank",RANKX(filteredByRegion,[Count] + [NameIndex])
        )
VAR TopProduct=
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            FILTER(
                tblRanked
                ,[Rank]=TopPos
            )
            ,[PRODUCT]
        )
VAR RESULT =
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE('table'[PRODUCT])
        ,'table'[PRODUCT] = TopProduct
        )
RETURN
    RESULT
```

...

```
TOP2 = 
    VAR TopPos = 2
...
TOP3 = 
    VAR TopPos = 3
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you just double-check some of your results at the row-total level? With no external filters applied, that should return REG-YH-33 for TOP3, though I get REG-YH-89 using your code.

Comment: I mean the total row, which you seem to have excluded in your picture. I imagine the OP would also want to see the TOP1, TOP2, etc. for ALL regions.

Comment: @JosWoolley, I use `VAR currentRegion = SELECTEDVALUE('table'[REGION])` It can't be a value in total with no filters.

Comment: @JosWoolley, I added the option to have a value in total. May be you are right with a guess, but there was no an input about that, and frankly speaking didn't think about it. But I'm still intersted how did you manage to get a value it total using my original code with no filters?

Comment: I replaced `SELECTEDVALUE` with `MIN` since I was testing in PowerPivot, not Power BI.

Comment: @JosWoolley, thank you for your competent feedback, and would like to have it in future ). Really, I'm very thankfull for stressing the issue and spending your time on it. Have a nice day.

Comment: I've posted another solution which I think may be more efficient. See if you can spot any issues.

Comment: Mik you are an absolute total champ! thank you for your time and effort this REALLY HELPED ME OUT I am so thankful, to answer some of your question, YES there will be times where there is a TIE between best selling products but for the practicality of this task it will not matter which one is which, but in the future I will be interested in creating a column that will show the TOTAL next to each row... THANK YOU GUYS AGAIN FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: You can call me - Mike.) Thank you for your kind words